# RFC realization for bias of microwave transistor circuits

Tags: amplifier, rf, bias, microwave

I saw the following configuration for the bias circuit of some microwave amplifier circuits.

I think in the left figure the RFC is realized using a quarter wavelength short circuited stub (because of the capacitors), but there is no by-pass cap in the right figure. How RFC is realized in this configuration?

Also there is an extra stub at the end of the short circuited stub. What is the purpose of this additional part?

[image]

---

Link to the references: see 
[page 4](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dl/Scans-005/Scans-00107098.pdf) and
[page 8](http://www.qsl.net/va3iul/Bias/Bias_Circuits_for_RF_Devices.pdf)

Also there are a few examples in the book "Microwave Transistor Amplifiers: Analysis and Design" by Guillermo Gonzalez, Prentice Hall, 1997, chapter 4.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the diagram conventions - but, what are the 'oblong' and square objects at the outboard end of the stubs (by the arrows in each case). If the stubs are the "tracks" from power outpur collector.drain and if the blobs are capacitors (as they may be) then they serve the short circuiting function and Cb x 3 are bias transistor emitter decoupling.  In any case the 1/4 wave stub acts as a short circuit in its own right and any capacitance to ground at that point is good practice but a bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 1/4 wave stub acts as a short circuit in its own right and any capacitance to ground at the "cold" end is good practice but a bonus.

I'm not familiar with the diagram conventions - but, what are the 'oblong' and square 'blobs' (symbols) at the outboard end of the stubs (by the arrows in each case).?
If the stubs are the "tracks" from power output collector & drain respectively, and if the blobs are capacitors (as they may be) then they serve the short circuiting function and Cb x 3 in the left hand diagram are primarily bias transistor emitter decoupling which also helps with any RF that gets beyond the stub.

---

Added:

The text associated with the second diagram [on page 22 in this document](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dl/Scans-005/Scans-00107098.pdf) explains the biasing feed arrangement. They say that the "track + square" symbol represents a 1/2 wave stub that is tapped at the 1/4 wave point.

The 1/2 wave stub appears as an open circuit to the amplifier and the 1/4 wave tapping is a zero voltage point where bias is applied. In an ideal system this point has no signal present and no additional decoupling is needed. In real world situations there will (usually) be some sort of additional capacitive decoupling in the bias feed "to keep Murphy honest".

They say -

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. The square symbols should be tracks, however I've added the links. Assuming they are capacitors,  the 1/4 wave stub is somehow terminated into a capacitive load (maybe in parallel to some impedance) and thus it's not short at the end anymore.

Comment: Those are DC biasing pads. The high impedance lines going to them act like RF chokes at the operating frequency.

Comment: @SMA.D IF the quarter wave stub is ideal you can terminate it in anything you wish and it will make no difference. 0 j0 = 0 j0 regardless. IF capacitors made a difference then the left hand diagram has the same  issue with CB x 3 - the physical distance is unknown and the capacitors appear at the stub end plus some extra reactance.  See addition to my answer

Comment: @RussellMcMahon input impedance of the quarter wave stub is z_in=z_0^2/z_L and is dependent on the terminating load, only if z_L=0 we have z_in=infinty.

Comment: Do you mean that the size (characteristic impedance) of the square track is not important?